# How to use returned GET hyperlinks as img src links in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, get

Currently I am sending an `XMLHttpRequest` to retrieve a `JSON` response. I want to take the links listed as "normal" but I am not sure how to reference them to get them into my list of HTML img elements. Here is the JSON response:

```js
{
  metadata: {
    code: 200
    message: "OK"
    version: "v2.0"
  } -
  data: {
    _links: {
      self: {
        href: "//z4photorankapi-a.akamaihd.net/customers/215757/media/recent/?count=20"
      } -
      first: {
        href: "//z4photorankapi-a.akamaihd.net/customers/215757/media/recent/?count=20"
      } -
      next: {
        href: "//z4photorankapi-a.akamaihd.net/customers/215757/media/recent/?next_id=czoyOToiLTHFkzE0NDM2OTE3MTQyMTPFkzIyNjIwOTU2NjMiOw~~&count=20"
      } -
    } -
    _embedded: [20]
    0: {
      _links: {...
      } -
      type: "IMAGE"
      source: "instagram"
      source_id: "398002460025587218_31000928"
      original_source: "http://instagr.am/p/WF_SDxjoYS/"
      caption: "Packing my first thredUP bag! #thredup #womenslaunch #bigmoney"
      video_url: null
      share_url: "http://www.photorank.me/photos/demo/1232903472"
      date_submitted: "2013-02-24T00:36:24+00:00"
      favorite: false
      location: {...
      } -
      images: {
        square: "https://z3photorankmedia-a.akamaihd.net/media/b/s/d/bsdniy/square.jpg"
        thumbnail: "https://z2photorankmedia-a.akamaihd.net/media/b/s/d/bsdniy/thumbnail.jpg"
        mobile: "https://photorankmedia-a.akamaihd.net/media/b/s/d/bsdniy/mobile.jpg"
        normal: "https://z3photorankmedia-a.akamaihd.net/media/b/s/d/bsdniy/normal.jpg"
        original: "https://z1photorankmedia-a.akamaihd.net/media/b/s/d/bsdniy/original.jpg"
      } -
      _embedded: {...
      } -
      _forms: {
        report: {
          title: "Report photo?"
          action: {
            href: "//z2photorankapi-a.akamaihd.net/media/1232903472/reports"
          } -
          method: "POST"
          fields: [3]
          0: {
            type: "email"
            prompt: "Email"
            name: "email"
            value: ""
            placeholder: "my@email.com"
          } -
          1: {
            type: "short-text"
            prompt: "Reason"
            name: "reason"
            value: ""
            placeholder: ""
          } -
          2: {
            type: "submit"
            prompt: ""
            name: "send"
            value: "Report"
            placeholder: ""
          } -
          -
        } -
      } -
      _analytics: {
        oid: "1232903472"
        t: "media"
        meta: [3]
        0: "user_agent"
        1: "event_type"
        2: "is_mobile" -
      } -
    } -
    1: {...
    } -
    2: {...
    } -
    3: {...
    } -
    4: {...
    } -
    5: {...
    } -
    6: {...
    } -
    7: {...
    } -
    8: {...
    } -
    9: {...
    } -
    10: {...
    } -
    11: {...
    } -
    12: {...
    } -
    13: {...
    } -
    14: {...
    } -
    15: {...
    } -
    16: {...
    } -
    17: {...
    } -
    18: {...
    } -
    19: {...
    } -
    -
  } -
}
```

My goal is to take those links and use them as the `src` for `img` tags in list in an html file.  I would really appreciate any help.

I was thinking I could reference it using `response.data._embedded[0].images.normal` but that does not seem to be working.

Here is the HTML code that I have:

```html
<ul id="photolist">
</ul>
```

And here is the Request that I am sending:

```js
var getData = function() {

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "http://photorankapi-a.akamaihd.net/customers/215757/media/recent/?auth_token=0a40a13fd9d531110b4d6515ef0d6c529acdb59e81194132356a1b8903790c18", true);
  xhr.send();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {

      var res = JSON.parse(xhr.response);

      for (var y = 0; res.data._embedded.length; y++) {

        var srclink = res.data._embedded[y].images.normal;
        var listItem = document.createElement("li");
        var image = document.createElement('img');

        //add listItem to the photolist
        document.getElementById('photolist').appendChild(listItem);
        //add the image to the list item
        listItem.innerHTML = image;
        //make the image src = the hyperlink from the JSON response
        image.src = srclink;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When the code gets to the point of trying to pull the image at this line:

```js
var srclink = res.data._embedded[y].images.normal;
```

I get the following response:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of undefined

> xhr.onreadystatechange @ sliderscript.js:41

Comment: post your html code so we can help you

Comment: just added.  thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
You have to parse the JSON result to use it as a proper object (I've rewritten it to use async XHR, but feel free to use synchronous if you have to):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://photorankapi-a.akamaihd.net/customers/215757/media/recent/?      auth_token=0a40a13fd9d531110b4d6515ef0d6c529acdb59e81194132356a1b8903790c18", true);


xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    //load image
    var res = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    var img = res.data._embedded[0].images.normal;
    document.getElementById("test").src = img;
  }
}
```

You should also avoid extra spaces in HTML attributes, like here:

```
<img id = "test" src =""/>
```

Replace it with

```
<img id="test" src=""/>
```

What you write is valid HTML, but increases pointlessly the document size.

Finally, if you want to write valid markup, try using a 1px white (or whatever color suits your needs) as initial src for your images, then replace the src attribute with javascript.

**EDIT 2**

To play with a list, this would be the right way to go:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    photoListFrag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    srcLink,
    image,
    listItem;

xhr.open("GET", "http://photorankapi-a.akamaihd.net/customers/215757/media/recent/?auth_token=0a40a13fd9d531110b4d6515ef0d6c529acdb59e81194132356a1b8903790c18", true);


xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    //load image
    var res = JSON.parse(xhr.response);

    for (var y = 0; y < res.data._embedded.length; y++) {
        image = new Image();
        image.src = res.data._embedded[y].images.normal;

        listItem = document.createElement("li");
        listItem.appendChild(image);

        photoListFrag.appendChild(listItem);

    }
    //add fragment to the photolist (once it's been filled with all the elements)
    document.getElementById('photolist').appendChild(photoListFrag);
  }
}
```

Works in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/superbiche/fuontbfo/4/

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I updated the JSON response but had to keep the other array elements (1 through 19) minimized because the response was too long.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  This worked, though I am still getting the same error now that I am inserting the image into a list.

Comment: How do you add it to your list ?

Comment: I will post it at the bottom of my question.

Comment: I edited my question to include the new error that is showing up.

Comment: @AnthonyKingJr. perfect!
Could you please mark this question as resolved and mark my answer as the right one?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are going the right way. Only thing you need to do is put that data in an img tag.

example:

```
<div class = "image-holder">
    <img id = "insta-image" src =""/>
</div>

<script>
    $.getJSON("http://photorankapi-a.akamaihd.net/customers/215757/media/recent/?auth_token=0a40a13fd9d531110b4d6515ef0d6c529acdb59e81194132356a1b8903790c18",{
    headers: {
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        },
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json",
    async: false
    }).success(function(response) {
        if(response !== "")
        {
            var img = response.data._embedded[0].images.normal;
            document.getElementById("insta-image").src = img;
        }
    }).error(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });


</script>
```

Comment: Hey I used this html snippet but the data fetching script always causes this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_embedded' of undefined

Comment: Thats because its async. It tries to look up that propperty but the response isnt there yet...ill update my code ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's actually throwing a new error now...since I am trying to make a dynamic list.  I edited my question to include the new error that is showing up.